# Bootstrap DataTables Restore Original Data After Custom Search

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap tables from [here](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/).
So, long story short, I create a customSearch for my tables :

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  data: mainData,
  customSearch: function(text) {
    if (text.length > 0) {
      // ---------------
      // ajax load data from server, THIS STEP WORKS PERFECTLY
      // ---------------
    } else {
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', mainData);
    }
  }
});
```

Let me explain it. So, the customSearch function do ajax and call Json data from server when user fill in search box. This step works perfectly.

But what I want is when the user delete the search's phrase, the original data is restore (As you can see in the ELSE statement).

BUT IT DOESN'T WORK. it return a console error :

```
too much recursion
```

any idea how to tweaks my code ?, my main purpose is to restore the original data after user leave the search box empty.

Thanks

Comment: You're getting the recursion error because when `text.length` is 0 you're hitting the else case, which then calls exactly the same function, then you hit the else case which calls the same function again, and so on. The first thing I'd try is removing the else case entirely, and see if that works.

Comment: It'll work, but my main purpose still not reached. How can i restore the original data back when the user leave the search phrase empty ?, the else statement was actually do the purpose. But if you ask me to remove it, how can i restore it back ?

Comment: OK, so in your ajax code that you've omitted, what does it return, or what does it do with the data that you get from the result of the ajax call? I guess you need to do the same thing in the else case, but using `mainData` instead of the ajax response. Can you try replacing the code in the else case with `return mainData;`?

Comment: AAAHHAAA !, okay, i just change the method, from customSearch, into onSearch. Everything works perfectly.

Comment: Good, glad you sorted it out.